# Data Calculation by month and name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have Sales Table with the following column

```
Date        / Total / Person Name

2019-05-25  / 500   / george
2019-05-28  / 800   / george
2019-01-15  / 100   / mark
2019-01-16  / 600   / mark
2019-02-18  / 500   / pavel
```

i want to make result as bellow

```
05(month)  / total 1300 / georga
1 (month)  / total 700  / mark
2 (motn)   / total      / pavel
```

to sum every month each person ho many sales has

Answer (score 1):

To group by the start of the month:

```
select  dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, t1.date), 0) as themonth,
        sum(t1.total) as total,
        t1.name
from t1
group by t1.name, dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, t1.date), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(Total)
    ,DATEPART(MONTH, DATE)
    ,[Person Name]
FROM myTAble
GROUP BY DATEPART(MONTH, DATE)
    ,[Person Name]
```

Comment: What happens if there is more than 1 year of data in the table?